# Custom Activity: Interaction Specific Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am following this tutorial for creating a custom activity:

https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node

It says to :

> In update-case config, replace '**your-activity-customer-key**' with
>   the interaction-unique 'key' value (ie. REST-1) for create-case
>   activity. You can get it by querying for details about your
>   interaction:

```
headers: 
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json
GET https://jbinteractions.exacttargetapps.com/fuelapi/interaction/v1/interactions/<guid>?extras=all&versionNumber=9
```

I have tried querying this endpoint and got a 404 error. Is this dated? What new endpoint should I be targeting to get this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct GET endpoint for you to use:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/[guid]
```

You can retrieve the guid value from the Journey URL. The guid appears between the `%23` string (a URL encoded # character) and before the `/` character. For an example, see the Interaction identifier highlighted below.

[image: interactionId]